# Django Have all submit buttons go back to main page

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have an app with one main page that has several buttons.  Each button performs some view functionality and then returns the main page. When the button below is clicked it returns that main page but the url says: http://localhost:8080/abc_app/backup_system.  This creates some POST resend prompt/issue when I hit the browsers refresh button.

Is there anyway for me to return http://localhost:8080/abc_app instead of  http://localhost:8080/abc_app/backup_system?

Thanks ahead of time.

```html
<form action="{% url 'abc_app:backup_system' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
   <button type="submit" name="index" class="btn btn-primary btn-block float-right"value="index">Refresh</button>
</form>
```

```
def backup_system(request):
    status = g_abc_api.backup_system()
    return index(request)
    # I have tried HttpResponseRedirect('/compost') as well.
    # If possible, it would be great to have the 'status' variable returned from the API available in  index(request) so I can display errors.

def index(request):
    '''
    Populate context
    ''
    return render(request, 'abc_app/index.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you share your view code more(how you render your template and how you redirect after submitting form?)

Comment: If you are using `POST` then its recommended that you return `HttpResposeRedirect`to another view, `POST` method should always redirect, and not render templates.

Comment: Thanks.  Any thoughts on how I may be able to pass the 'status' variable into the HttpResponseRedirect so that I can display an error message? I have tried passing the value via kwargs but it doesn't seem to make it (ex. return redirect('index', kwargs={'status': status }))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HttpResponseRedirect

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
...
return HttpResponseRedirect('your_template_name')
```